# angularjs route go back to previous filtered state instead of original state

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have a table, display a list of items, using dirPagination for filtering data and pagination. Code like this

```
<tr dir-paginate="result in results | filter:query |  itemsPerPage: 10">
```

and the input filter like this

```
<input ng-model="query" placeholder="Search">
```

For each item in the results table, i have a 'View Details' button

```
<a href="#/viewDetails/id" >view details </a>
```

This button will takes you to the details of the time using angular-route as below. And details controller is as below as well. It has a back function that takes user back to list view.

```
   $routeProvider.when('/viewDetails/:id/', {
        templateUrl: 'details.html',
        controller: 'detailsCtrl'
    }).when('/listView/', {
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl'
    });

app.controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    var guid = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.back = function () {
        $location.path('/listView');
    };
}
```

So my question is, when clicks back, i want to takes me back to the filtered state. For example, in list view, i filter all items that name contains 'test'. 
Then I click view details to see details of one item.  When i go back, i want to still apply the filter, only show items that name contains 'test'

The current code i have, will take me back to original state, where no filter gets applied.  Any suggestion?

Comment: the only way to accomplish this would be to store the value of the filter in a service, then apply the filter (even if it's empty) every time the `listCtrl` is instantiated.  when you move forward, update the filter value, and when you go back, the filter will be applied after the view is loaded.

Comment: this seems promising?    $scope.$watch('query', function (text) {
      $location.search('color', color); 
  });